# Is there a way to write JavaScript so it is more readable when dealing with many callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, coding-style

I am working in JavaScript. I get more and more frustrated because of the way the code looks. The code is so nested that I very soon need to invest in a third 37" monitor to prevent damaging my fingers for all time.

Here is some working code I am working on right now:

```
$(function () {
    var mainContainer = $('#mainContainer'),
        countyContainer = $('#countyContainer'),
        workAreaContainer = $('#workAreaContainer');
    $('body').fadeIn(400, function() {
        mainContainer.slideDown(400, function() {
            ShowLoader();
            ListCounties(function(counties,success) {
                if (success) {
                    HideLoader();
                    for (var i = 0; i < counties.length; i++) {
                        if (counties[i] != "") {
                            countyContainer.append(
                                '<div class="col-md-3 county-result-item">'+
                                    '<h3>'+counties[i]+'</h3>'+
                                    '<i class=" '+FA('fa-folder-open','3x')+' text-center" style="color:'+RandomColor()+'"/>'+
                                '</div>'
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    var countyResultItem = $('.county-result-item');
                    countyResultItem.on('click', function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var county = $(this).text().split("(")[0];
                        if (county != "") {
                            ShowLoader();
                            countyContainer.slideUp(400);
                            FetchWorkAreas(county,function(workAreaData,success) {
                                if (success) {
                                    for (var i = 0; i < workAreaData.workAreas.length; i++) {
                                        workAreaContainer.append(
                                            '<div class="col-md-3 workArea-result-item">'+
                                                '<h3>'+workAreaData.workAreas[i]+'</h3>'+
                                                '<i class=" '+FA('fa-folder-open','3x')+' text-center" style="color:'+RandomColor()+'"/>'+
                                            '</div>'
                                        );
                                    }
                                    HideLoader();
                                    workAreaContainer.slideDown(400, function() {
                                        var workAreaResultItem = $('.workArea-result-item');
                                        workAreaResultItem.on('click', function(event) {
                                            event.preventDefault();
                                            var selectedWorkArea = $(this).text().split("(")[0];
                                            FetchJobListings(workAreaData.countyID,selectedWorkArea,function(jobListings,success) {
                                                if (success) {
                                                    console.log(jobListings);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    })
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function FetchJobListings(countyID,selectedWorkArea,callback) {
        $.post('Fetch.php', {fetch: 'jobListings',countyID : countyID, selectedWorkArea: selectedWorkArea}, function(data) {
            if (data) {
                callback(data,true);
            }
        });
    }

    function FetchWorkAreas(county,callback)
    {
        $.post('Fetch.php', {fetch: 'workAreasID',county:county}, function(data) {
            if (data && data.workAreas.length > 0) {
                callback(data,true);
            }
        });
    }

    function ListCounties(callback)
    {
        $.post('Fetch.php', {fetch: 'counties'}, function(data) {
            if (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    callback(data,true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function RandomColor() {
        var colors = ["#cea547","#7e8b58","#002c44","6da6a7"];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
        return colors[rand];
    }

    function FA(icon,size) {
        var iconSize = '';
        if (typeof size != undefined) {
            iconSize = size;
        }
        return 'fa '+ icon+' fa-'+size;
    }

    function ShowLoader() {
        if ($('.imgLoader').length === 0) {
            var loaders = ["loading1.gif","loading2.gif","loading3.gif","loading4.gif"];
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*loaders.length);
            $('#mainContainer').append('<div class="imgLoader"><img class="imgLoader img-responsive img-center" src="imgs/'+loaders[rand]+'" /><h3 class="text-center">Laster</3></div>');
        }
    }

    function HideLoader() {
        $('.imgLoader').fadeOut(400,function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

This just hurt my eyes and I get a little sad really since it is important for me that code is readable and pretty, and not ending up looking like a fish ladder:

```
                                            }
                                        });
                                    });
                                })
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am still what I call a novice when it comes to JavaScript and it may be something fundamentally I have not noticed. But basically, is there a way to keep the code so it doesn't indent 1000 times by the time I am done with it?

Comment: Use a promises framework.

Comment: This question has been asked a lot: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20avoid%20callback%20hell%20javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of borderline [Spaghetti Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

There are a few things you can do, the first being to split out all your functions so that they exist independently as smaller processes. For example:

```
ListCounties(function(counties,success) {
    if (success) {
```

Rather than create an inline function (that isn't reusable), ask yourself what is it that I want to do with a list of counties, and build that independently.

```
// write a nice comment here to explain what the function does and what the arguments mean
function handleCountyList(countries, success){

}
```

Now you can call your `ListCounties` as follows:

```
ListCounties(handleCountyList);
```

By splitting out all your functions into more manageable pieces, you will avoid the ladder.

This should also make your code much more maintainable, as it becomes easier to read, think about, debug and update. Empathise with other developers, and ask, *"If I showed my friend this code, could she easily understand what it does?"*

---

If you want to get a bit more advanced, and callbacks are what is annoying you, try promises. They are semantically, and functionally better in my opinion, and allow you to do things like:

```
ListCounties().then(function(counties){
    // do something with the counties
});
```

Promises come in different flavours, but this library is a good start: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this for me.

Comment: I will look into promises frameworks right away, and thanks for the tip about Bluebird.

Answer (score 1):

Name your callbacks and separate the logic, e.g.

```
ListCounties(function(counties,success) {
                if (success) {....
```

becomes:

```
ListCounties(processCounties);

function processCounties(counties,success)   
   if (success) {...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code there are a couple of things you could do, but before that it's much more important to **be consistent across your codebase** - with most IDEs allowing you to collapse blocks it'd be a little bit more difficult to deal with a shift in coding style than deep nesting

---

### **Guard Clauses**

You could replace your

```
ListCounties(function(counties,success) {
     if (success) {
         ...
```

with

```
ListCounties(function(counties,success) {
     if (!success)
         return; 

     ...
```

to reduces 1 level of nesting. You can apply this for most of the checks that'd you do before deciding to proceed with the bulk of the code.

Be warned that this would this would make the code less readable if the guard condition is not very obvious. For instance while this is a good place for a guard clause (the guard clauses serves more like a filter)

```
KillWasps(function(bug) {
     if (bug !== "wasp")
         return

     // code to deploy nuclear warheads
     ...
```

this would **NOT** be a good place for a guard clause (the guard block actually has program logic and 2nd block which executes for `wasps` is more of a fall-through block, just like a fall-through block for switch cases)

```
HandleInsect(function(bug) {
     if (bug !== "wasp") {
         // code to sign up bug for insects anonymous
         return
     }

     // code to deploy nuclear warheads
     ...
```

An `else` block (and a thick magazine) is what I would use in this case.

**Related reading** :  http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/

---

### Delegated Event Handlers

I see you have one places where you do (for when you just added some .county-result-item elements)

```
var countyResultItem = $('.county-result-item');
countyResultItem.on('click', function (event) {
     ...
```

You might want to consider moving this to a delegated event handler

```
countyContainer.on('click', '.county-result-item', function(event) {
     ...
```

And you can move this from inside your current handler that does the `append` to an outer scope.

Of course, if you don't have any `.county-result-item` in your DOM this is a good way to perplex someone if they can't easily figure out where `.county-result-item` are / are added - this would be **BAD**, so keep your `append` logic close your delegated click handlers if that is the case.

**Related reading** : http://api.jquery.com/on/ (see the section on delegated events)

---

Other methods are already listed in other answers.